# How to find overlapping fields of view?

Tags: opengl, computer-vision

If I have 2 cameras and I'm given the positions and orientations of the cameras in the same coordinate system, is there any way I could detect overlapping fields of view? In other words, how could I tell if something that's displayed in the frame of 1 camera is also displayed in another? In addition, I'm also given the view and projection matrices of the 2 cameras.

Comment: Seems like you have two questions here =) So I'm clear- do you specifically want to know if an object in world space can be seen by two cameras or are you just trying to detect if two fields of view are overlapping?

Comment: it's the second question - just trying to detect if two fields of view are overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect two overlapping fields of view you'll want to do a collision check between two viewing frustums (viewing volume).

[image]

A frustum is a convex polyhedra so you can use the separating axis theorem to do it.

See [here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169).

However, if you just want to know if an object that is displayed in the frame of one camera is displayed in the frame of another camera the best way to do that is to transform the world space coordinates from said object in to the viewport space of both cameras. If both coordinates land within the range [0:width, height:0] for both and the z coordinate is positive, then the object is in view of both cameras.

[This page](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html) has a great diagram of the 3D transformation viewing pipeline if you want to read more on what viewspace and worldspace are.